# Is there a JS function or a way to return the number in 4 digits format?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have function that needs to return a String+ number . 
the number can be from 0 to 1000 . But I always want number to be in format 0000 ,0001 ,0002,0116 etc ..
How can I do It ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `padStart` method. Hope this helps.

```js
const padWithZeros = (number) => number.toString().padStart(4, 0)

console.log( padWithZeros(1) )
console.log( padWithZeros(10) )
console.log( padWithZeros(121) )
```